# Sort reviews such that the logged in user review appears first and all other reviews are sorted in descending order of date

Tags: node.js, mongoose

The following mongoose query retrieves the title and a nested review array sorted in descending order of creationdate:

```
Post.findById(request.params.id).select({title:1, 
    reviews:{$sortArray:{input:"$reviews", sortBy:{creationdate:-1}}}    }).
    populate("reviews.userid",{name:1})
```

This is a sample of the output from this query:

```
{
    "post": {
        "_id": "642ef80f7f06439acdd8552b",
        "title": "pets",
        "reviews": [
            {
                "userid": {
                    "_id": "64112ea99f072b412d1a30bb",
                    "name": "gfdfgdfgdfgf"
                },
                "heading": "review1",
                "review": "e in its savage simplic..............",
                "creationdate": "2023-05-14T02:56:38.000Z",
                "_id": "64604de6eb800ae06763e20a"
            },
            {
                "userid": {
                    "_id": "64112f269f072b412d1a30c1",
                    "name": "Peter Smalls"
                },
                "heading": "new hea",
                "review": "outside of Dr......",
                "creationdate": "2023-05-10T18:19:49.000Z",
                "_id": "645be0450de30c43011752e5"
            },
            {
                "userid": {
                    "_id": "64112f1c9f072b412d1a30bd",
                    "name": "Mary fdg"
                },
                "heading": "review3",
                "review": "From the reports that I h......",
                "creationdate": "2023-05-10T15:48:25.000Z",
                "_id": "645bbcc9848bc9f70e4d4016"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I extend this query to still sort the nested review array in descending order of creationdate, however if the logged in userid (e.g. ObjectId('64112f1c9f072b412d1a30bd')) has a review for that post, it'll appear first (regardless of if it qualifies for the sort order) and all other reviews are sorted in descending creationdate?